# delete a single row if a match is found in an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a problem deleting certain rows from a sheet.

The sheet contains only two columns, name and age:

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| John | 20 |
| Alicia | 10 |
| John | 20 |
| Alissa | 22 |
| Alissa | 22 |
| Alicia | 10 |

The script gets a list of names and the elements of this list are searched in the sheet to eliminate the row where these names are found. So if you pass a list to the script with the the integers [20, 10, 22], the sheet should only contain the rows of John, Alice and Alissa once. I.e. only the first occurrence is deleted. For now I have tried this:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

function clearRow() {
    let ages = [22, 20, 10];
    ages.forEach(age => {
        let ageFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(age.toString());

        var result = ageFinder.findAll();
        console.log(result.length);
        Logger.log("Delete row: " + result[result.length - 1].getRow());
        sheet.deleteRow(result[result.length - 1].getRow());
    })
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that all occurrences are removed, even though only 20, 22 and 10 appears once in the array.

Expected output for the array [20,22,10]:

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| John | 20 |
| Alicia | 10 |
| Alissa | 22 |

Could someone help me with this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) would make your code cleaner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can use this:

**Your Code:**

```
function clearRow() {
    let ages = [20, 22, 10];
    ages.forEach(age => {
        let ageFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(age.toString());

        var result = ageFinder.findAll();
        if(result.length>0){
          sheet.deleteRow(result[0].getRow());
        }
    })
}
```

**Output:**

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

---

### What it does?

1. Create a text finder to look for specific string within your sheet using [Sheet.createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
2. Get all matching cells using [TextFinder.findAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findall)
3. Get the row index of the first matching cell by getting zero index of the result array
4. Delete row using [Sheet.deleteRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I didn't know that the google script team offered a createTextFinder method. However, how would you deal with this problem if it were not a string? @ron-m

Comment: You mean, the data in the cell is an integer?,  you can still use TextFinder just make sure that the input to the createTextFinder() will be a string. example createTextFinder('20'). TextFinder will consider all data in your sheet as a text when finding the match

Comment: Additional info, TextFinder is also available in range class, if you want to look for a specific text on a specific range rather than the whole sheet, you can use [Range.createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: I just tried an integer as follows sheet.createTextFinder(integerInArray.toString()); and it doesn't work. The above code you posted removes all occurrences, what I'm looking for is to remove only the first occurrence leaving the rest.

Comment: In your original post, your expected result will be John Alicia Alissa Alissa (which means you aims to remove the last duplicate for the names specified). Please confirm which duplicate you really want to remove? the first duplicate or the last duplicate

Comment: can you also update your code that has `integerInArray.toString()` so that i could check. My hypothesis is that `integerInArray` is an array when you convert it to string, you need to use `integerInArray[arrayIndex].toString()` or use `integerInArray.forEach(integer => { sheet.createTextFinder(integer.toString()); }`

Comment: `articles` is not defined, it should be `ages.forEach` and use `result[0].getRow()` to delete first occurrence. Before i update my answer, are you really sure you want to match it by their age rather than their names? if you have different names with same age there is a chance that only 1 row will be deleted from either of the names that has the same age

Comment: You are absolutely right that it does not make much sense to filter by an int that may actually be assigned to an n number of names. However, the main problem I had was the elimination of a single entry. That is, the priority is that if the array only appears once, it can only be removed once from the datasource.  By the way, you were right about  ```integerInArray.forEach(integer => { sheet.createTextFinder(integer.toString()); }``` in this way I convert each element into a string. Google Script is amazing I just discovered it :D

Comment: Sorry, can you please update the question and provide an expected output in a table as well so i can fully visualize. Oh you mean if the data entry is only 1, it should not be removed?. Please see the updated answer, i included a condition  `if (result.length>1)` before deleting the row.Thank you

Comment: I have updated the question, I think the output example makes it easier to understand. In short, if we have a = [20, 22, 10] and b=[22, 22, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20] only 3 elements in b must be removed.

Comment: you really want to go through with the age?  and you mention only 3 elements will be removed (you prefer the 1st occurrence?). Ill just update my answer based on your last comment as requirement

Comment: I want to delete those rows that contain the age of the array, but only once. I.e. if John appears 5 times with age 20, it should only be deleted once if John appears 4 times in the original sheet.

Comment: what if john and alicia has age of 20, john appears 3 times then alicia 2times. the 1st occurrence of 20 will be deleted from john. is that correct?. Another scenario is what if only john has age of 20 but john has 1 entry, should it be deleted as well?

Comment: Yes, thats correct as I assume that each user will have a unique age and a unique name (I'm just learning). If there is only one entry with this condition, it must also be deleted.

Comment: Noted, please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the name and break the loop.

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

function removeRow(){
    let names = ['John', 'Alissa'];
    for(let i=data.length - 1; i>=0 ;i--){
        for(let j=articles.length -1; j>=0 ;j--){
            if(data[i][0] == articles[j]){
                console.log(i)
                sheet.deleteRow(i);
                names.unshift();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```